# Postgresql union to get sales for all days and hours and a summary row

Tags: postgresql, union

We have 2 tables and a query to get sales data for every hour and every day, and a summary row for each day.

Tables:

1. sales_table - sales data
2. date_hour - lists all dates and their respective hours (24 hours each day)

Query:

```
with b as (
SELECT
    a.purchase_date,
    CAST(DATE_PART("HOUR", CAST(a.purchase_date AS DATETIME)) as INTEGER) AS 
Hour,
    COUNT(a.quantity) AS QtyCount,
    SUM(a.quantity) AS QtyTotal,
    SUM((a.item_price) AS Price
FROM sales_table a
GROUP BY Hour, a.purchase_date
),
a as (
     SELECT
          DATE_FORMAT(DateT, "yyyy-MM-dd") AS datet,
          CAST(hourt AS INTEGER) AS hourt,
          QtyCount,
          QtyTotal,
          Price
     FROM date_hour
), 
c as (
     SELECT
       a.purchase_date,
       CAST(DATE_PART("HOUR", CAST(a.purchase_date AS DATETIME)) as INTEGER)  
 AS Hour,
       COUNT(a.quantity) AS QtyCount,
       SUM(a.quantity) AS QtyTotal,
       SUM((a.item_price) AS Price
FROM sales_table a
GROUP BY a.purchase_date
) --summary row subquery
Select   --summary row
     c.purchase_date,
     "Day Total" AS Hour,
     if(c.QtyCount is null, 0, c.QtyCount) QtyCount,
     if(c.QtyTotal is null, 0, c.QtyTotal) QtyTotal,
     if(c.Price is null, 0, c.Price) AS Price
FROM a LEFT JOIN c
ON a.datet = c.purchase_date
UNION
Select
     a.datet AS Date,
     a.hourt AS Hour,
     if(c.QtyCount is null, 0, c.QtyCount) QtyCount,
     if(c.QtyTotal is null, 0, c.QtyTotal) QtyTotal,
     if(c.Price is null, 0, c.Price) AS Price
FROM a LEFT JOIN b
ON a.datet = b.purchase_date AND a.hourt = b.Hour
ORDER BY Date, c.hour
```

Sample result:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Date</th><th>Hour</th><th>QtyCount</th><th>QtyTotal</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>6</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>9</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>11</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>6.99</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>12</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>13</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>15</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>69.95</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>16</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>17</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>18</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>19</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>21</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>22</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>23</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-02</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>76.94</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>6</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>9</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>11</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>12</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>13</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>15</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>16</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>17</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>18</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>19</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>21</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>22</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-03</td><td>23</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>209.85</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>6</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>7</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>9</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>11</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>12</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>13</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>14</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>15</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>16</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>17</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>18</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>19</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>21</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>22</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>23</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2018-11-04</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>209.85</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The query works but the summary row is not listed at the top.  Is it possible to list the summary row at the top of each day (before hour 0 of that day) and include a summary row when there were no sales (11/3 in the above example) as zeros across?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without examining too deeply I think all you need is a a column to assist with ordering

```
with (....
 ...
)
Select   --summary row
     0 as ordr,
     c.purchase_date,
     "Day Total" AS Hour,
     if(c.QtyCount is null, 0, c.QtyCount) QtyCount,
     if(c.QtyTotal is null, 0, c.QtyTotal) QtyTotal,
     if(c.Price is null, 0, c.Price) AS Price
FROM a LEFT JOIN c
ON a.datet = c.purchase_date
UNION
Select
     1 as ordr,
     a.datet AS Date,
     a.hourt AS Hour,
     if(c.QtyCount is null, 0, c.QtyCount) QtyCount,
     if(c.QtyTotal is null, 0, c.QtyTotal) QtyTotal,
     if(c.Price is null, 0, c.Price) AS Price
FROM a LEFT JOIN b
ON a.datet = b.purchase_date AND a.hourt = b.Hour
ORDER BY Date, ordr, hour
```

I suggest you might want to investigate [ROLLUP](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-rollup/) which may simplify your query.somewhat.

---

To get a summary for every date, you need to use the cte "a" as the base table, an left join the sales_table, see "c" below This is untested and only a proposal, you will need to do any debugging.

```
with a as (
     SELECT
          DATE_FORMAT(DateT, "yyyy-MM-dd") AS datet,
          CAST(hourt AS INTEGER) AS hourt,
          QtyCount,
          QtyTotal,
          Price
     FROM date_hour
    )
, b as (
SELECT
    a.purchase_date,
    CAST(DATE_PART("HOUR", CAST(a.purchase_date AS DATETIME)) as INTEGER) AS 
Hour,
    COUNT(a.quantity) AS QtyCount,
    SUM(a.quantity) AS QtyTotal,
    SUM((a.item_price) AS Price
FROM sales_table a
GROUP BY Hour, a.purchase_date
    )
, c as (
     SELECT
       a.datet as purchase_date,
       CAST(DATE_PART("HOUR", CAST(st.purchase_date AS DATETIME)) as INTEGER)   AS Hour,
       COUNT(st.quantity) AS QtyCount,
       SUM(st.quantity) AS QtyTotal,
       SUM((st.item_price) AS Price
FROM a
left join sales_table st ON a.datet = c.purchase_date
GROUP BY a.datet
) --summary row subquery
```

**btw** "a" "b" "c" etc. are very frustrating aliases. I think things like "st" (Sales Table) are more useful.

Comment: How clever, the summary row is now at the top with your suggestion!  Thank you, @Used_By_Already!  Is there any way to return a summary row (all zeros) for days with no sales, such as 11/3 in the example result? I'm not familiar with ROLLUP, how would that work for this situation?

Comment: ROLLUP removes the need for multiple unioned queries. Beyond the scope of this question, but you can visit the link I provided to start.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to return a summary row (all zeros) for days with no sales, such as 11/3 in the example result?

Comment: have added to the answer, a suggestion.

Comment: Got it to work by changing "a.purchase_date" to "a.datet" in the c cte.  Thank you so much!

Comment: In the question, cte "c" states `FROM sales_table a` so, yes it uses the alias "a" but does NOT use the cte "a" - there is a big difference. This is also why you should adopt a more meaningful alias naming convention

Comment: **ah** our comments "crossed-over". Thanks, glad I could help.

Comment: Yes, more meaningful naming convention makes sense and will save a lot of headaches. Thanks for the tip!